Keycloak Policy Enforcer with Spring Boot 3.3 and Spring Security 6 – Performance Issue with Public APIs
I have integrated Keycloak's policy enforcer with my Spring Boot 3.3 application, which uses Spring Security 6. However, I am encountering a performance issue.
We have over 50 public APIs, all of which are configured in the policy enforcer file. When a request is made, the policy enforcer checks each public API, causing a delay before the response is returned.
Is there a more efficient way to handle this setup, particularly for public APIs, so that the policy enforcer doesn't have to verify each one individually? I would appreciate any suggestions to improve overall performance.

Policy enforcement on the authorization server sucks. You'd have much better perfs using Spring Security for controlling access to resources on ... resource servers. In the linked answer, I develop more arguments than just perfs.
